# lib32gcc1 has no installation candidate

Tags: server, 21.04

I am trying to install lib32gcc1 as part of a requirement to run a valve game server on Ubuntu Server 21.04. I can get all of the other prerequisites done but the system cannot install lib32gcc1. I followed these two guides [guide 1](https://aarmastah.xyz/misc/tf2vps.php) [guide2](https://linuxgsm.com/lgsm/tf2server/)

Comment: So far as I can tell, that package only ever contained a single documentation directory - I can't imagine it's really required for running a game server

Answer (score 0):

The [first guide](https://aarmastah.xyz/misc/tf2vps.php) looks outdated and too complicated.

You can install `steamcmd` from [official repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=steamcmd) as simple as:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo apt-add-repository multiverse
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install steamcmd
```

And then use official [SteamCMD guide](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamCMD).